# Inside jquery function html href code not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the problem was in the line

```
  $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html(
        '<a href="edit.html?id'='+sid'">Edit</a>'),alert(sid+"Id2:"+item['id']),
```

here   the alert is getting clearly.. but in browser the path shows

**//localhost:8080/sample/teacher/edit.html?id'=sid'**

here not shows the value of sid that is id 41
i want to show the link as

**localhost:8080/sample/teacher/edit.html?id=41** or any other dynamic id value

i don't know why this happen the code is not right

Here var sid is an array  & push  value id to array.. the alert shows the value of sid & item['id']
correctly.

```
   $.each(responseData, function(index, item) {

        var sid = [];
                                
        $('#student').append(           
        $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html(
            item['name']), 
    
        $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html(
            item['phoneNo']),

            sid.push(item['id']),

        $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html(
            '<a href="edit.html?id'='+sid'">Edit</a>'),alert(sid+"Id2:"+item['id']),

        $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html(
                '<button onclick="lightbox1_open();">Delete</button>'),
        $('<br />').val(item['id']).html(
            item['']));         
        
    });
```

if you know the answer please share here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the string concatenation is the problem, try

```
$('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html('<a href="edit.html?id=' + sid + '">Edit</a>')
```

Comment: i got an error when change the code Field error in object 'student' on field 'id': rejected value ['   sid   ']; codes [typeMismatch.student.id,typeMismatch.id,typeMismatch.long,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [student.id,id]; arguments []; default message [id]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long' for property 'id'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "'sid'"]

Comment: what is the value of sid

Comment: the sid value is dynamic value it's change  example 41

Comment: the browser shows the link as  /teacher/edit.html?id=' + sid + '

Answer (score 2):

change `id'='+sid'"` this by `id='+sid+'"`

```
$('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html('<a href="edit.html?id=' + sid +'">Edit</a>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use like this

```
'<a href="edit.html?id=' + sid + '">Edit</a>'
```